You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate>...] but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist
I'm trying to build and to run on Apple M1 Mac, macOS: Sonoma 14.6.1, iOS SDK 17.5 a .NET8 MAUI Blazor Hybrid project/app using the following CLI command:
dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-ios
Build completes OK. iPad emulator (iPad 13-inch (M4)) starts OK.
But then runtime error is fired:
2024-09-08 00:40:25.537593+0300 MonkeyFinderHybrid[7126:180036] Microsoft.iOS: Socket error while connecting to IDE on 127.0.0.1:10000: Connection refused
2024-09-08 00:40:26.470239+0300 MonkeyFinderHybrid[7126:179989] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2024-09-08 00:40:26.608463+0300 MonkeyFinderHybrid[7126:179989] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.InvalidOperationException', reason: 'RootViewController cannot be null (System.InvalidOperationException)

The crash log header is the following:


> dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-ios 

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Detected signing identity:
          
    Bundle Id: com.companyname.MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp
    App Id: com.companyname.MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp
  MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp -> /Users/myUserName/Learning/test_dotnet/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp.dll
  Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/dev/ttys000 --stderr=/dev/ttys007 --terminate-running-process 05E5DFD0-824E-40A5-8281-45D74BA0E5BC com.companyname.MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp
  com.companyname.MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp: 7126
2024-09-08 00:40:25.537593+0300 MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp[7126:180036] Microsoft.iOS: Socket error while connecting to IDE on 127.0.0.1:10000: Connection refused
2024-09-08 00:40:26.470239+0300 MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp[7126:179989] You've implemented -[ application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "fetch" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
2024-09-08 00:40:26.608463+0300 MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp[7126:179989] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.InvalidOperationException', reason: 'RootViewController cannot be null (System.InvalidOperationException)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue(Object xamlelement, XmlName propertyName, Object value, Object rootElement, INode node, HydrationContext context, IXmlLineInfo lineInfo)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit(ValueNode node, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.RootNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit(RootNode rootnode, HydrationContext visitorContext, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Assembly rootAssembly, Boolean useDesignProperties)
  
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.InvalidOperationException', reason: 'RootViewController cannot be null (System.InvalidOperationException)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue(Object xamlelement, XmlName propertyName, Object value, Object rootElement, INode node, HydrationContext context, IXmlLineInfo lineInfo)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit(ValueNode node, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ValueNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.RootNode.Accept(IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, INode parentNode)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit(RootNode rootnode, HydrationContext visitorContext, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Assembly rootAssembly, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, String xaml, Boolean useDesignProperties)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load(Object view, Type callingType)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[MainPage](MainPage view, Type callingType)
   at MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp.MainPage.InitializeComponent() in /Users/myUserName/Learning/test_dotnet/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.SourceGen.CodeBehindGenerator/MainPage.xaml.sg.cs:line 26
   at MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp.MainPage..ctor() in /Users/myUserName/Learning/test_dotnet/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp/MainPage.xaml.cs:line 7
   at MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp.App.CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState) in /Users/myUserName/Learning/test_dotnet/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp/MyMAUIBlazorHybridApp/App.xaml.cs:line 12
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application.Microsoft.Maui.IApplication.CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IApplication application, UIWindowScene windowScene, NSDictionary[] states)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ApplicationExtensions.CreatePlatformWindow(IUIApplicationDelegate platformApplication, IApplication application, UIApplication uiApplication, NSDictionary launchOptions)
   at Microsoft.Maui.MauiUIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)

...


[UPDATE]
After adding the following markup snippet:


    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key> 
      <array>     
         <string>fetch</string> 
      </array>



to the Info.plist file, clearing the build artefacts (dotnet clear) and rebuilding/running the project's app the second error line disappeared, but still there is a runtime error:

2024-09-10 14:33:50.344736+0300 MonkeyFinderHybrid[97380:1881229] Microsoft.iOS: Socket error while connecting to IDE on 127.0.0.1:10000: Connection refused
2024-09-10 14:33:51.435404+0300 MonkeyFinderHybrid[97380:1881163] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.InvalidOperationException', reason: 'RootViewController cannot be null (System.InvalidOperationException)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue(Object xamlelement, XmlName propertyName, Object value, Object rootElement, INode node, HydrationContext context, IXmlLineInfo lineInfo)
...


XCode version



xcodebuild -showsdks

    
   DriverKit SDKs: 
     DriverKit 23.5                 -sdk driverkit23.5

   iOS SDKs:  
     iOS 17.5                       -sdk iphoneos17.5

   iOS Simulator SDKs: 
     Simulator - iOS 17.5           -sdk iphonesimulator17.5

    macOS SDKs: 
      macOS 14.5                        -sdk macosx14.5
    ...


dotnet --info


    .NET SDK:
     Version:           8.0.401
     Commit:            811edcc344
     Workload version:  8.0.400-manifests.57f7c351
     MSBuild version:   17.11.4+37eb419ad

    Runtime Environment:
     OS Name:     Mac OS X
     OS Version:  14.6
     OS Platform: Darwin
     RID:         osx-arm64
     Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/

    .NET workloads installed:
    Configured to use loose manifests when installing new manifests.
     [maui]
       Installation Source: SDK 8.0.400
       Manifest Version:    8.0.72/8.0.100
       Manifest Path:       /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk-manifests/8.0.100/microsoft.net.sdk.maui/8.0.72/WorkloadManifest.json
       Install Type:        FileBased


    Host:
      Version:      8.0.8
      Architecture: arm64
      Commit:       08338fcaa5

    .NET SDKs installed:
      6.0.403 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
      7.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
      8.0.401 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

    .NET runtimes installed:
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.8 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]


[UPDATE 2]
I have published the subject MAUI Blazor Hybrid project here.
I have retested it on Win11/.NET8 - it worked OK.
But when building on Mac
dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-ios

there is still runtime error and it's new one:

   The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
   Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.

The full error log for

dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-ios

is as the following:


  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Detected signing identity:
          
    Bundle Id: com.companyname.monkeyfinderhybrid
    App Id: com.companyname.monkeyfinderhybrid
  MonkeyFinderHybrid -> /Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/bhw/blazor-hybrid-workshop/Part 6 - Advanced Topics/MonkeyFinderHybrid/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/MonkeyFinderHybrid.dll
  Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
  Simulator device failed to install the application.
  The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
  Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.
  Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
    Failed to install the requested application
    The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
EXEC : error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.companyname.monkeyfinderhybrid' on the device 'iOS 17.5 (21F79) - iPad Pro 13-inch (M4) (16GB)': simctl returned exit code 22 [/Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/bhw/blazor-hybrid-workshop/Part 6 - Advanced Topics/MonkeyFinderHybrid/MonkeyFinderHybrid.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(1056,5): error MSB3073: The command "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/bin/mlaunch --launchsim bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/MonkeyFinderHybrid.app/ --device ":v2:runtime=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-5,devicetype=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-13-inch-M4-16GB" --stdout /dev/ttys001 --stderr /dev/ttys001 --wait-for-exit:true" exited with code 1. [/Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/bhw/blazor-hybrid-workshop/Part 6 - Advanced Topics/MonkeyFinderHybrid/MonkeyFinderHybrid.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]

Build FAILED.

EXEC : error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.companyname.monkeyfinderhybrid' on the device 'iOS 17.5 (21F79) - iPad Pro 13-inch (M4) (16GB)': simctl returned exit code 22 [/Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/bhw/blazor-hybrid-workshop/Part 6 - Advanced Topics/MonkeyFinderHybrid/MonkeyFinderHybrid.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(1056,5): error MSB3073: The command "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/bin/mlaunch --launchsim bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/MonkeyFinderHybrid.app/ --device ":v2:runtime=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-5,devicetype=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-13-inch-M4-16GB" --stdout /dev/ttys001 --stderr /dev/ttys001 --wait-for-exit:true" exited with code 1. [/Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/bhw/blazor-hybrid-workshop/Part 6 - Advanced Topics/MonkeyFinderHybrid/MonkeyFinderHybrid.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)


[UPDATE 3]
Added to info.plst 


<key>CFBundleVersionString</key>
 <string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>



still getting build error for:

dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-ios



  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  Detected signing identity:
          
    Bundle Id: com.companyname.monkeyfinderhybrid
    App Id: com.companyname.monkeyfinderhybrid
  MonkeyFinderHybrid -> /Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/DWHP6/MonkeyFinderHybrid/bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/MonkeyFinderHybrid.dll
  Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
  An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
  Simulator device failed to install the application.
  The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
  Ensure your bundle contains a valid CFBundleVersion.
  Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
    Failed to install the requested application
    The application's Info.plist does not contain a valid CFBundleVersion.
EXEC : error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.companyname.monkeyfinderhybrid' on the device 'iOS 17.5 (21F79) - iPad Pro 13-inch (M4) (16GB)': simctl returned exit code 22 [/Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/DWHP6/MonkeyFinderHybrid/MonkeyFinderHybrid.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(1056,5): error MSB3073: The command "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/bin/mlaunch --launchsim bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/MonkeyFinderHybrid.app/ --device ":v2:runtime=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-5,devicetype=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-13-inch-M4-16GB" --stdout /dev/ttys000 --stderr /dev/ttys000 --wait-for-exit:true" exited with code 1. [/Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/DWHP6/MonkeyFinderHybrid/MonkeyFinderHybrid.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]

Build FAILED.

EXEC : error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.companyname.monkeyfinderhybrid' on the device 'iOS 17.5 (21F79) - iPad Pro 13-inch (M4) (16GB)': simctl returned exit code 22 [/Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/DWHP6/MonkeyFinderHybrid/MonkeyFinderHybrid.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.401/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(1056,5): error MSB3073: The command "/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8020/tools/bin/mlaunch --launchsim bin/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/MonkeyFinderHybrid.app/ --device ":v2:runtime=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-17-5,devicetype=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro-13-inch-M4-16GB" --stdout /dev/ttys000 --stderr /dev/ttys000 --wait-for-exit:true" exited with code 1. [/Users/nardo/Learning/test_dotnet/DWHP6/MonkeyFinderHybrid/MonkeyFinderHybrid.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:05.87

Tried:

dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-MacCatalyst

on the same Mac M1 computer - it worked like a charm.

You can try to add a pair of key/value in the info.plist file in your project: <key>UIBackgroundModes</key> <array>     <string>fetch</string> </array>, then rebuild the project.

@Shuowen He-MSFT: Thank you, I have added a key/value pair that you have proposed but I have got the same runtime error after rebuilding/starting the project's application.

What is your Xcode version? Have you tried deleting the obj and bin folders of the project and rebuilding it? And does the same error occur when running in other iOS simulators?

@Shuowen He-MSFT: I have added info on XCode and SDKs and .NET SDKs versions to the [UPDATE] section. I have also noted that the subject error doesn't happen anymore after info.plist file's edits, still there is another runtime error (see [UPDATE 2]) , when running the same project on Win11 it works well.
Here is the info.plist file.

you can try to add <key>CFBundleShortVerionString</key><string>1.0</string> in the info.plist file.

@Shuowen He-MSFT: I have tried to add CFBundleShortVerionString key into the info.plist file. Still getting the same error - see [UPDATE 3]. In the same time I have the other sample apps, which do build and run well on my Mac on iPad simulator. They do not have CFBundleShortVersionString key in their info.plist files. The error could be caused by something else. I have to give up trying to solve the issue currently as this is just a sample project and I have the urgent work to do.
I'm going to return to searching for the subject issue solution within a few weeks.

I tested your project on my Mac, my Xcode version is also 15.4, I can successfully build the project through VS Code and VS (even though Maui does not support VS now, but this can be used as a workaround)：

Indeed, many reasons can cause this error, such as the package is not loaded properly, or the file format in the Resources folder causes an error, you can refer to solutions in  Cannot launch ios app on simulator or device "does not contain valid CFBundleVersion".

Thank you for your test. I also can build the project using dotnet CLI for net8.0-MacCatalyst. I can't build the project for net8.0-ios. I'll have to spend more time investigating the stuff from the link you've posted - my first try to remove some resources wasn't successful. What version of VS 2022 for Mac have you used in your test build - 17.6.14 ?

The project can not only be successfully built on Mac Catalyst platform, but also on .net-ios 8.0. Yes，my vs for mac‘s version is 17.6.14

I have installed VS for Mac 17.6.14 but it doesn't recognize the .NET8 projects. Does dotnet build -t:Run -f net8.0-ios command line successfully builds and runs the subject project on your system, or successful build and run can be fulfilled on VS for Mac 17.6.14 only? (The VS for Mac 17.6.14 did setup .NET6 and .NET7 SDK but not .NET8 SDK, which was already installed. That seems to be correct setup. Why VS for Mac 17.6.14 doesn't recognize .net8-ios, .net8-android and .net8-MacCatalyst as target platforms while dotnet cli does recognize them is unclear(/another puzzle) for me.)

My vs for mac can recognize .NET8 normally. Have you tried to reinstall vs for mac? Or you can try vs for mac preview
